# php shell_exec copy file with space in filename

Tags: php, file, copy, space, shell-exec

I am using a shell_exec() function to copy file in php(On windows IIS). The command I am using is :

```
shell_exec("copy ..\\images\\$image_url temp\\$filename\\media\\image1.png");
```

This is working fine until the image name($image_url) is not having space in the name. But if the image is having space in name this just fails.

Any idea how to escape the $image_url. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
shell_exec("copy \"..\\images\\$image_url\" \"temp\\$filename\\media\\image1.png\"");
```

Basicly, it's like on the command-prompt. If you're having spaces in parameters you have to put quotes around them. Around the parameters - not around the spaces. ;-) How else should the copy command know, where one parameter ends and another begins.

Also make sure that `$image_url` and `$filename` are safe. If user have influence on their contents they could possibly do anything on your system. Be careful!

Answer (score 0):

Mark " " with "\ ".

```
shell_exec("copy ..\\images\\".str_replace(" ", "\ ", $image_url)." temp\\".str_replace(" ", "\ ", $filename)."\\media\\image1.png");
```